# iOS light linen background?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I really want to know if there's a way to get iOS's light linen background.  Here's what it looks like:
[image: ios maps app open with menu open, map looks like a pealed up piece of paper. It is on an iPhone running a version of iOS before ios6]

Is there a way to access this by merely using the built-in SDK?  Or do I have to find an image like this somewhere?

---

**EDIT:** I didn't want to use private APIs, so here's what I did.  I grabbed the image this way:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 640.0f, 960.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor underPageBackgroundColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"underPageBackground.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagepath atomically:YES];
```

And here is the resulting png in retina resolution: (click on thumbnail to open)

[image: click for full resolution]

Hope this is useful to someone. :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `[UIColor underPageBackgroundColor]`. And here is a [link](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIColor) with useful information and samples.

Comment: Very nice, never knew about that!  Will it get me rejected by Apple if I use it?

Comment: Agreed, I was unaware of the wiki. A good reference to know of.

Comment: Just found this warning from Apple somewhere on the 'net in regards to Apple's rejection of their app: `The non-public API that is included in your application is underPageBackgroundColor.`  So, I'd use this one with care.

Comment: Well, you can always capture this image from emulator and use it a png file... Interesting finding though.

Comment: As of iOS 5, this method is now public, and can be used in Apps submitted to the App Store, without rejection.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure it is exactly the one (seems darker to me) but, you can choose the "Scroll View Textured Background Color" in Interface Builder. To do so, when selection a color choose the dropbox to the right instead of the color box on the left.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's the dark one that I already found.  I was wanting the light one, but thanks again for your answer.

Comment: another option would be to choose the darker one and put it above a white view. Afterwards set the alpha of the textured background to something 0.8 to 0.9 and it should lighten up. (And you don't have to use a private API nor a png)

Comment: @sudorm-rf Is there a way to get the dark one programmatically?

Comment: @zekel: You could just change the code in my original post to be from `underPageBackgroundColor` to `scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor`. Does that do what you want?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should be able to find this background in the SDK(it should be the default one for this kind of "flick page up" function) or on google (try looking for `UIStockImageUnderPageBackground.png`).

Otherwise - it looks like a pattern. What you could do is to import the attached screenshot, then cut a bit without the shadows and fill a blank canvas with it, so that the sides match forming the original pattern.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't really a solution to get the actual image but you can easily just make the texture. I just pulled up a tutorial on how to make it in photoshop. [iOS Linen tute here](http://elixirgraphics.com/index.php/entries/blog_creating_an_ios_linen_texture_in_photoshop)
This way you can make it whatever color you want!