# underPageBackgroundColor is approved?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uicolor

can i use

`[UIColor underPageBackgroundColor]`

or my app will be rejected from apple? It's just for some background colors in some view controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's documented and it's in the header file.  You can use it.

Why do you think you might not be allowed to use it?

Answer (score 3):

It's a documented API, so it's public, so you should be fine to use it.

Comment: well i've seen some post around that said that might be rejected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694023/ios-light-linen-background so i just asked about it! Thanks a lot just an hour before the submit!

Comment: The date on that other post is before iOS5 was released, I believe. This API is new in iOS5, but since iOS5 is well out of the barn, it's OK to use it.